# How to use React Router to ignore an ErrorBoundary for specific errors?

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, jsx, react-router-dom

The app I'm working on uses Error Boundaries, which I'm pretty new to. We also use React Router, which I'd like to use to make some redirects to the homepage in the case of a few certain errors (instead of jumping straight into the error boundary).

For example, I'd like to redirect to a dashboard component if the datasetId doesn't exist, but this case always leads straight to the error boundary being mounted. I'm unsure how to 'override' this, or catch the error and redirect before the error boundary does its thing.

Here's some relevant code to illustrate this example:

Routes:

```
const Dataset = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route
        name="data-snapshot"
        path="/datasets/:datasetId/versions/:snapshotId"
        component={DatasetQuery}
      />
      <Route
        name="data-dataset"
        path="/datasets/:datasetId/"
        component={DatasetQuery}
      />
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

Component in Routes

```
const DatasetQuery = ({ match }) => (
  <ErrorBoundary error={error} subject={'error in dataset page'}>
    <DatasetHook
      datasetId={match.params.datasetId}
      draft={!match.params.snapshotId}
    />
  </ErrorBoundary>
)
```

Also has an error Boundary:

```
const DatasetHook = ({ datasetId, draft }) => {
  const {
    data: { dataset },
    loading,
    error,
  } = useQuery(draft ? getDraftPage : getDatasetPage, {
    variables: { datasetId },
  })
  if (loading) {
    return <Spinner text="Loading Dataset" active />
  } else {
    if (error) Sentry.captureException(error)
    return (
      <ErrorBoundary error={error} subject={'error in dataset page'}>
        <DatasetQueryContext.Provider
          value={{
            datasetId,
          }}>
          <DatasetPage dataset={dataset} />
          <FilesSubscription datasetId={datasetId} />
        </DatasetQueryContext.Provider>
      </ErrorBoundary>
    )
  }
}
```

Say the datasetId doesn't exist, and someone goes to an invalid route. How can I redirect to a different component as opposed to loading the error boundary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to "override" error boundary and handle redirect manually, you can utilize the fallback UI feature in error boundaries.

In your `ErrorBoundary` component, check to see if the error thrown is from dataset, and return a specific UI for it. You can refer to React's documentation for an example: https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#introducing-error-boundaries